# Fast access to models in a ArrayDataProvider based on their key?

Tags: php, yii2

I have an `ArrayDataProvider` of `Items`, returned by a function of the following form:

```
public function builder() {
  $items = Item::find()->all();
  $dataProvider = new ArrayDataProvider([
     'allModels'  => $items,
     'pagination' => false,
     'id'         => 'items_dp'
  ]);
  return $dataProvider;
}
```

For various reasons, I need the code for this function to stay as it is.

My question is, if I have a list of `Item` `id`s, `myItemIds`, is there any way to rapidly select `Item`s in the DataProvider having those `id`s one by one?
For example, in an application like:

```
$provider = builder();
$myItemIds = [112,321,422];
$superItems = [];
foreach ($myItemIds->each() as $itemId) {
  $superItem = // builder based on data from the Item in DataProvider with id = $itemId and other things;
  $superItems[] = $superItem;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Given your scenario and the constraint of keeping the `builder` function as is, to select `Items` in the `ArrayDataProvider` with specific IDs (`$myItemIds`), you would need to iterate through the data provider's models and check if an item's ID is in your list of IDs. Here is an example of how you could achieve this:

```php
$provider = builder(); // Assuming this calls your builder function and returns an ArrayDataProvider
$myItemIds = [112, 321, 422];
$superItems = [];

// Get all models from the provider
$allModels = $provider->allModels;

// Iterate through the list of IDs you want to find
foreach ($myItemIds as $itemId) {
    // Search for the item by ID in the array of all models
    $key = array_search($itemId, array_column($allModels, 'id'));
    if ($key !== false) {
        // If the item is found, you can process it as needed
        $item = $allModels[$key];
        // Assuming you have some logic to build a "super item" from an item
        $superItem = // Your logic to transform $item into $superItem goes here;
        $superItems[] = $superItem;
    }
}

// Now $superItems contains your processed items
```

This code snippet assumes that `$allModels` contains an array of objects where each object has an `id` property that you can compare against your list of desired item IDs (`$myItemIds`). The `array_search` function is used in conjunction with `array_column` to find the index of each item by ID in the array of all models. Once an item is found, you can then process it according to your needs and add the result to the `$superItems` array.

Note: This approach assumes that the `id` field is directly accessible on your item objects and that `$allModels` is a simple array of objects. If your actual data structure is different, you may need to adjust the search logic accordingly.

Comment: Thank you, I had thought of this "brute force" approach, but I was wondering if there's a more efficient way to do it.

Comment: If you mean with *'a more efficient way to do it'*, avoiding the for each iteration, you can use `ArrayHelper::getValue()`.
https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-helpers-arrayhelper#getValue()-detail